# What does Singleton objects extending a superclass and mix in traits means?

Tags: scala

I am reading Programming in scala and in chapter 4, I came across the following lines which I could not understand

> singleton objects extend a superclass and can mix in traits. Given each singleton object is an instance of its superclasses and mixed-in traits, you can invoke its methods via these types, refer to it from variables of these types, and pass it to methods expecting these types.

Things I know:
1) singleton objects are where static methods are written (corresponding to java)
2) traits are like interface

Please explain the above line and if possible with an example.
Also, are the variables under the object block also static?

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, that line is just stating that singleton objects (defined with the object keyword) can be passed around just like normal instances of objects.

For example, consider the following code

```
scala> trait X
defined trait X

scala> def doSomething(x: X) = { println("Something") }
doSomething: (x: X)Unit

scala> object Y extends X
defined object Y

scala> doSomething(Y)
Something

scala> class Z extends X
defined class Z

scala> doSomething(new Z)
Something
```